# Need help to write query that uses max and group by by using nhibernate queryover

Tags: sql, nhibernate, group-by, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, queryover

I am new to nhibernate and i fail to find out how to do this sql query by using queryover api:

```
SELECT category, MAX(number) as "Highest number"
FROM table1
GROUP BY category;
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
SELECT department, MAX(number) as "Highest number" FROM table1 GROUP BY category;
```

to this:

```
SELECT department, MAX(number) as "Highest number" FROM table1 GROUP BY department;
```